# Writing data on another tab

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a data from one tab to another.

I get an error on `ws2.target2.Offset(m + row_num, l).Value = temp`.

```vb
Sub data_collection()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tabNames(7) As String

tabNames(0) = "a"
tabNames(1) = "b"
tabNames(2) = "c"
tabNames(3) = "d"
tabNames(4) = "e"
tabNames(5) = "f"
tabNames(6) = "g"
tabNames(7) = "h"

For i = 0 To 7

    Set ws = Sheets(tabNames(i))
    Set target = ws.Range("B1")
    
    Do Until target.Offset(j, 0).Value = "Total:"
    
        If target.Offset(j, 0).Value = "1Req Detail" Then
        
            Set ws2 = Sheets("REQ_DETAILS")
            Set target2 = ws2.Range("A1")
            
            Do Until target.Offset(j, 0).Value = "Total Open Reqs:"
            
                If target.Offset(j, 0).Value <> "" Then
                
                    For l = 0 To 9
                    
                        temp = target.Offset(j, l).Value
                    
                        ws2.Select
                        ws2.target2.Select
                        ws2.target2.Offset(m + row_num, l).Value = temp
                        
                    Next
                    
                    row_num = row_num + 1
                                    
                End If
            
                k = k + 1
            
            Loop
               
        End If
        
        j = j + 1
    
    Loop
       
    j = j

Next
End sub
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please include that in your question. Also, these do not seem to be defined anywhere... `m` and `row_num` - What are their values when you get the error?

Comment: target2 is a range not a worksheet method, ws2.target2 should just be target2.

Answer (score 1):

`target2` is a range so remove `ws2` from `ws2.target2.Select` and `ws2.target2.Offset(m + row_num, l).Value`. Also with the second Do loop `k = k + 1` should probably be `j = j + 1` otherwise the loop never exits. Move the target and you don't need `j`. `ws2` and `target2` don't change so move outside the loop.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub data_collection()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim target As Range, target2 As Range
    Dim i As Long, c As Integer, row_num As Long, iLastRow As Long
    
    Dim tabNames
    tabNames = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")
    
    Set ws2 = Sheets("REQ_DETAILS")
    Set target2 = ws2.Range("A1")
    row_num = 0

    For i = 0 To UBound(tabNames)
    
        Set ws = Sheets(tabNames(i))
        Set target = ws.Range("B1")
        iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
        Do Until target.Value = "Total:" Or target.Row > iLastRow
            If target.Value = "1Req Detail" Then
                 
                Do Until target.Value = "Total Open Reqs:" Or target.Row > iLastRow
                    If Len(target.Value) > 0 Then
                        'copy row
                        For c = 0 To 9
                            target2.Offset(row_num, c).Value = target.Offset(0, c).Value
                        Next
                        row_num = row_num + 1
                    End If
                    Set target = target.Offset(1, 0)
                Loop

            End If
            Set target = target.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set variables m, row_num and j starting values. Before vars usage write m=0: j=0: row_num=0 or other values.